# validating argument types for different functions using a single interface (without using inspect)

Tags: python, types, metaclass, inspect

I wish to check the types of the arguments for each function in the module (without making use of inspect module). 
The easiest solution I have done myself is to implement the check in each function separately.

```
def func1( num1, num2 ):  # the two params must be integers
    if isinstance( num1, int ) and isinstance( num2, int ):
        # ...function code...
        pass
    else:
        return

def func2( float1 ):  # The only param must be float

    if isinstance( float1, float ):
        # ...function code...
        pass
    else:
        return

def func3( str1 ):  # string
    if isinstance( str1, str ):
        # ...function code...
        print 'fdfd'
        pass
    else:
        return


# and, so on ...
```

But, want to do it at the module level, rather than doing it for each function. Each function can have different arguments. Please note that this is not function overloading. I was thinking of either writing a decorator or a metaclass. Here are the problems that I faced in both the approaches:-

1. Using a common decorator for all the functions:
   In this method, I am not able to access the actual variables defined inside each function, so scrapped this idea. Here is a closure (to be used as decorator) that I was planning to write :

> ```
> def dec( funcName ):
>     def typeChecker():
>         i = __import__( __name__ )
>         for m in map( lambda x: i.__getattribute__( x ), dir( i ) ):
>             if '__call__' in dir( m ):  #Identifying a real function or callable which can be treated as function
>                 ## Now, that the function is identified, what should I do here to type-check the arguments??
>     return typeChecker
> ```

Please provide some insights here as to how I can make this work.

2.Using a metaclass for creating function
I was just wondering if I could access the arguments being sent to a function using a metaclass and then, validate each of the argument, and then, return a brand new class which would be responsible for creating the function object. But, do not know how to do it. Is it a good way of solving this problem?

1 very good suggestion Martijn Peters has given - To use annotations. Is there something in Python 2.7 that we can use?

Comment: I dont understand the argument aginst the decorator. You have access to the arguments of the decorated function, but not the inner variables. So, what do you wnat? Arguments or local variables of the function?

Comment: Yes. Thats correct. I was initially thinking that I could access inner arguments. But, I was wrong. So, I quickly shifted my focus to metaclass.

Comment: I wouldn't do it with metaclasses. Try to avoid "magic". Did you consider dependency injection?

Comment: No.I'm new to that. Can you please explain. Ain't there a single way to do for all functions. The reason I'm asking this is there are many functions inside the module

Comment: Why do you need access to the local variables of a function to check the types of its arguments?  Decorators are the usual way to do this checking

Comment: @Ixop: Great news. I didnt have visibility of how it should be done using a decorator. If you can provide me a decorator do perform such an action, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this through a decorator is fairly easy - 
In Python 2 you'd have to decorate each function explicitly to annotate the type for
each parameter - or you could use some annotation using some markup on the doc-string,
and place a call on the bottom of the module that would iterate over all
objects on the module, and apply the decorator to each function
defined therein.

In both cases a decorator like this could suffice:

```
from functools import wraps
from itertools import count

def typechecker(*types, **kw_types):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            for position, type_, arg in zip(count(), types, args):
                if not isinstance(arg, type_):
                    raise TypeError("Argument in position %s should be a %s"
                                    % (position, type_))
            for key, type_ in kw_types.items():
                if key in kw_types and not isinstance(kw[key], type_):
                    raise TypeError("Argument %s should be a %s"
                                    % (key, type_))
            return func(*args, **kw)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

And you can see it working like this:

```
>>> @typechecker(int, int)
... def mysum(a,b):
...    return a + b
... 
>>> mysum(2,3)
5
>>> mysum(2.0,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in wrapper
TypeError: Argument in position 0 should be a <type 'int'>
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

My inclination would be something like this:

```
class A(object):
    def func(self, arg):
        result = self._get_func(arg)(arg)

    def _get_func(self, arg):
        # Create and return the appropriate function here.
        # You have a variety of options, e.g. arg.__class__ (if it exists),
        # or use a bunch of isinstance checks, etc.
        # Please bear in mind that this is really unpythonic!!
        if isinstance(arg, basestring):
            pass
```

If you're going to be calling the function a lot, this is obviously inefficient, so you would want to cache your specific functions, and try to pull from the cache first inside `_get_func`.

```
def _get_func(self, arg):
    if arg.__class__ in self._cache: # Or whatever
        return self._cache[arg.__class__]
    else:
        pass # Create and return the appropriate function here.
```

Of course you can override the `_get_func` method as needed (this ought to work at module level or class-level, though I'd probably prefer classes for clarity).

Also it's worth mentioning that this is really unpythonic. It's generally much cleaner to just write separate functions out in the open if they need to do different things, rather than hiding them inside function constructors. Or at least, "better to ask forgiveness" and use `try`/`except` blocks to encapsulate operations that only apply to specific types/classes.

Comment: Can you please explain how do we validate/ type-check each argument here?